# Angular2 - *ngIf on string interpolated value fetched from web service

Tags: angular

I have to display two mutually exclusive buttons 'MARK COMPLETED' and 'COMPLETED'. If the task status is OPEN then 'MARK COMPLETED' needs to display, whereas if the task status is closed then 'COMPLETED' button needs to display.

```
<div *ngFor="#task of tasks" class="demo-updates mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
    <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand mdl-color--teal-300">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{task.taskname}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
    {{task.taskdesc}}  {{task.taskstatus}}
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">                
                <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">{{task.assignedto}}</a>


    <a [routerLink]="['/AllTasks']" *ngIf="{{task.taskstatus}}='OPEN'" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" (click)="onClickMark(task)">Mark Completed</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/CompletedTasks']" *ngIf="{{task.taskstatus}}='CLOSED'" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Completed</a>


</div>
```

I tried `*ngIf="{{task.taskstatus}}='OPEN'"` , but it's   not working. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`*` already indicates to Angular that it needs to process the value as expression. `{{}}` in expressions is invalid.

Use instead:

```
*ngIf="task.taskstatus=='OPEN'"
```

Also for compairson `==` instead of `=` (assignment) is required.

Comment: Awesome .. thanks a lot. quick question.. How can I reload the component view upon I click 'mark completed' button ? This page displays only OPEN tasks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "reload"?

Comment: Basically when I click the 'mark completed' button, it posts the task status to the server. I want to stay on the same page, but make sure this task is not displayed here.(as this page displays only open tasks)

Comment: You can use `*ngIf` to display a different part of the component depending on a status in the model or you can use the router to switch between components that are displayed at `<router-outlets>` like explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: I was thinking more on the lines of change detection .. the data for my current view changes as the status is changed, so this needs to be reloaded.

Comment: That's what Angular does by default. When the model changes it updates the view. Maybe I still don't understand well enough what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry.. I'll create a new post.

Comment: I am facing the issue with ngIf for string comparision. Is any additional module is required for the ngIf to work. I tried this solution still getting error something like:
Parser Error: Unexpected token == at column 10 in [dataType?=='red'] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@36:5 ("
<div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="dataType?=='red'">
<table class="table table-stripped table-hover"><!--  -->
  <th"

Comment: Where does `[dataType?=='red']` come from? Do you have that in your components template? That looks like invalid markup.

Comment: "dataType" is a string variable that i have in component.I need to compare the value of variable with the hard code text in this case say "red" for ngIf condition to be true

Comment: You can't use variables or expressions inside `[...]` at least not if `[...]` is on the left side of `=` like `[...]="..."`

Comment: Then the cause is probably `?==`. Is this a new TS operator? I haven't worked with Angular since more than a year and don't know this operator. It's probably not (yet?) supported in templates.

Comment: Thanks for help.. rightly pointed out the issue.. == used instead for ?==. I read somewhere that ?== checks first for null value.

Comment: That only works for `.` vs `?.`, but not for other operators.